# Mono to SQL Server with Windows Auth

Tags: sql-server, mono, windows-authentication

**Quick...**

How to use Windows Authentication to SQL Server with the [Mono SQL Client](http://www.mono-project.com/SQL_Client) running on Windows *without* a username+ password in the connection string?

**More...**

- We have to use Mono to support multiple platforms for some components of our app
  This is an external limitation that we can't change
- We will run the components that access the database **only** on Windows
  The portability/OS-agnostic features of the Mono SQL Client add no value

That is, any component running on non-Windows will not access the SQL Server database

- The process runs under some Windows user (real user, service account, whatever)
- Embedding username and passwords is a *bad thing*
  No matter what angle you come from

So, how can we enable the Mono SQL Client to read the NT Logon Token of the user running the process and pass this to SQL Server? Just like MS .net does?

- Is there a flag or setting that isn't well documented
- Do we need to implement our own extension?
   
  If so, are we *really* the first folk to want to do this?

There are 5 other questions (currently) tagged Mono and SQL-Server: they don't answer this...

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but one has to wonder if you could treat AD like the Kerberos server that it is and get a ticket to use for your authentication.  This is a really interesting problem!

Comment: @BenThul: We'll investigate it. Make it an answer please: I'll upvote. It may help us to solve the problem too.

Comment: Oh... I don't know that I'd consider what I have as an answer yet. I just hope it leads to one.

Comment: As far as I know, SQL Server's Windows authentication relies on AD, which has no counterpart on UNIX or Linux. In that case, you should not expect Mono to have that implementation, unless you write it on your own. Mono usually focus the portable parts, due to its limited resources.

Comment: @Siva: yes, correct ( I mentioned it), but has anyone ever worked around this or published some extension? This is the point of my question...

Answer (score 10):

This is not as easy to accomplish as it sounds. As I'm sure you know, [Mono SqlClient](http://www.mono-project.com/SQLClient) has support for NT authentication:

> Has a connection string format for NT Authentication:
>   Server=hostname;Database=databaseName;User
>   ID=windowsDomain\windowsUserid;Password=windowsPassword;Integrated
>   Security=SSPI

But of course, you want the simpler form of `Integrated Security=SSPI` and let the NT authentication handshake use the current process credentials. And here lies the problem. While trivial to retrieve the current process user name (identity), is impossible for a process to discover it's own credentials *password*. When doing NT authentication an Windows process does not actually do the authentication, but instead is asking the [Locas Security Authority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721592(v=vs.85).aspx#_security_local_security_authority_gly) (aka. LSASS.EXE, trivia: don't attach a debugger to it ;) ) to authenticate this process. Which means that any library that wants to achieve the same must use the same protocol, ie. ask LSA to authenticate it. The actual details, for the curious, are in the sequence of [`AcquireCredentialHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374713(v=vs.85).aspx), [`InitializeSecurityContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375507(v=vs.85).aspx), [`AcceptSecurityContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374704(v=vs.85).aspx) as described in [Using SSPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380535(v=vs.85).aspx). I did not study the mono source for SqlClient, but I'm pretty sure they use some [GSS-API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff842418%28v=prot.10%29.aspx) library for the authentication, *not* SSPI. therefore, by definition, they require to know the password since they are going to do the Kerberos exchange *themselves*, not ask LSA to do it on their behalf.

This is, as you can tell, speculation and more of a guess on my side, but I would be surprised to hear a different story. While it is certainly possible to fork or patch Mono.Data.Tds and 
modify the authentication implementation to use SSPI instead of GSS, this would, by definition, be a non-portable Windows specific implementation. I would guess there is little incentive for it given that the #1 attraction point of Mono is that is *not* Windows specific. I'm afraid you are going to have to implement it on your own.

Comment: We have to use Mono for different reasons: but non-portability isn't an issue for the components that connect to the database. And we can avoid passwords in plaintext if we do implement it

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't make sense for *you*. I'm saying is probably not implemented by mono.

Comment: @RemusRusanu explanation is correct. Mono does not implement **integrated** password-less connections to SQL server for the reasons he stated. Of course this is all open source so it's likely possible to add this to non-Windows platform. Be sure to share your findings with the community :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use [NTLM Authorization Proxy Server](http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net) and connect to SQL Server through the proxy.